# Appstore Connect subscriptions and in-app purchase does not appear for selecting in Prepare for Submission

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

My first submitted app version with subscription and iap of status `Ready to Submit`, I am able to add them at the In-App Purchases and Subscriptions section:

[image]

[image]

Now the app after being rejected, the status of those subscription and iap also changed to `Deverloper action needed` in these pages:

[image]

Inside these pages I resubmited those subscription and iap(not resubmitting the app) and Apple reviewed then changed them to the status of `Approved`.

[image]

However I checked the live app on Appstore, nothing changed, no iap or subscription there for users to buy.

I thought, may be I needed to resubmit a new app version with bug fixing and select those `Approved` subscription and iap again. But in Prepare for Submission page, the modal does not show those for selecting instead showing a newly-created iap of status `Ready to Submit`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1)IAP/subscriptions do not appear in the VERSION screen because the IAP/SUB has not been submitted/approved
2)the main reason IAP/SUBS have not been submitted/approved is because they are missing metadata

just go to the IAP/SUB and update an screenshot and put something in the notes and you'll see the IAP/SUB to be added to the review version